# Dell XPS 13 9343 keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, dell, backlight

I have just re-installed 15.04 after updating my older BIOS to a newer version, prior to this re-installation the keyboard back light was functional; however, it doesn't seem to be working anymore after I did the re-installation. I feel like it may be something trivial as a setting which I need to configure, or a driver issue, but I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Nothing happen when you click on the "F10" key ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell XPS 13 9343 - keyboard backlight on at boot Ubuntu 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689907/dell-xps-13-9343-keyboard-backlight-on-at-boot-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.